# JSON mapping to C# class

Tags: c#, json

I have a piece of JSON like this:

```
{
"Site 1": [
    {
        "Stuff": [
            "detergent",
            "det1"
        ],
        "productLine": "Hay",
        "revenue": {
            "1": 3123,
            "2": 123123,
            "3": 123123
        }
    },
    {
        "Stuff": [
            "detergent",
            "det2"
        ],
        "productLine": "Machine",
        "revenue": {
            "1": 343123,
            "2": 1231321323,
            "3": 321
        }
    }
],
"Site 2": [
    {
        "Stuff": [
            "detergent",
            "det1"
        ],
        "productLine": "Hay",
        "revenue": {
            "1": 111,
            "2": 123123,
            "3": 3213
        }
    },
    {
        "Stuff": [
            "detergent",
            "det2"
        ],
        "productLine": "Machine",
        "revenue": {
            "1": 11123,
            "2": 3255,
            "3": 6575
        }
    }
]
}
```

I want to map this to C# class but my problem is the names `Site1` and `site2` are what I would think should be a class name?  Is there a way to represent this as a C# object?

Comment: This JSON doesn't validate. Try it on http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: my bad, ive fixed it :/

Comment: I'm a big fan of http://json2csharp.com.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your root object is actually a `Dictionary<string, List<YourClass>>` and `YourClass` will look like this:

```
public class YourClass
{
    public string[] Stuff { get; set; }
    public string productLine { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, int> revenue { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can deserialize your json like this:

```
var dic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<YourClass>>>("Your json string goes here...");
```

Comment: oh that is great thanks a lot! i should have got this myself!

Comment: You are welcome man. If this is your answer so mark is as answer.

Answer (score 0):

On your c# classes that map the same object graph as the json you can add attributes to the Class and properties to map the json exactly, eg for lowercase json properties etc.

see: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm